# Chrome: Disabling nVidia card on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, nvidia-graphics-card

For debugging purposes I need to run chrome without using the nVidia card but instead with the intel chip. I know there is this post from 7 years ago, but the linked projects and resources are heavily outdated and so I'm posting an updated question: How to disable nVidia and use the intel chip for chrome in Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: What is outdated is your Ubuntu. 17.10 is EoL since July 2018!! Please always run a supported release. That said you may be able to disable the dGPU in UEFI settings. If not then typically in Ubuntu users install the Nvidia drivers then use the Nvidia X Server Settings to select the desired profile and reboot. I really don't understand how someone wanting to 'debug' stuff don't know this already.

Comment: "I really don't understand how someone wanting to 'debug' stuff don't know this already" - Because you cannot not be all knowing? I started using Ubuntu in 2018 and never had this desire to switch the GPU. But thanks, will try the UEFI settings

Comment: You may want to upgrade Ubuntu as well. Your question would be off-topic in AskUbuntu for that reason alone. But maybe you know that already and that's why you posted it here? If so, bad move, your question won't be closed for that reason but will probably be downvoted a lot. Upgrade your Ubuntu to a supported release, 18.04 LTS or the current 19.10. Maybe then you won't need to be 'debugging'...

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia So if the question was without the hint of the version number it would have suited your guidelines? You know some people work for a reason on a certain version. Ever heard of "never change a running system"?

Comment: @ironmouse Not my guidelines, actually it's the site rules: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic . And re: the old saying "never change a running system" that's absolutely NOT applicable to OSes that frequently require security updates, especially when connected to the internet. It's the same logic for Linux, Windows and Mac and every other OS under the sun. Ubuntu provides LTS with 5 years support cycle, every other non-LTS release is supported for 9 months only. Not upgrading when it's needed it's patently dangerous.